# PRAW: Replying to a post

Tags: python, reddit, praw

As the title says, I'm unable to find the function in PRAW to reply to a post on Reddit.

I've written a rather simple bot so far, which looks for new posts on a certain subreddit. My problem is that once finding the submission, I can't find how to post a reply to it.

Answer (score 8):

It's unclear if by "submission" you mean a submission to reddit or if you're referencing a comment on a submission to reddit. If it's the former, you're looking for the [Submission#add_comment](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=add%20comment#praw.objects.Submission.add_comment) method. If you have the submission bound to variable name `s`, then you can do the following:

```
s.add_comment('This is my comment. There are many like it, but this one is mine.')
```

If you're looking for how to reply to a comment, you want to use the [Comment#reply](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.16/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=comment#praw.objects.Inboxable.reply) method. If you have the comment bound to variable name `c`, then you can do the following:

```
c.reply("Here is a reply to your comment.")
```

Answer (score 5):

As of October 2018, `submission.add_comment()` is no longer possible in PRAW.

The new call is [`submission.reply()`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission.reply)